# XCode UITests fail to run with Unexpected Exit Error (Bot only)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

My XCode UI tests are failing to run with a bot even when simply running the default testExample class (with no code). Instead, I receive an error:

> Testing failed:   Test target UIBotTest encountered an error (Early
>   unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart
>   will be attempted)
>   ** TEST FAILED **

Outside the bot, my tests are running and passing, with no such failure appearing.
One solution I tried to implement is utilizing a system alert handler to handle a Notification Permission alert upon first startup of the app as follows:

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc]init];
    [self addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription:@"Notification Handler" handler:^BOOL(XCUIElement * _Nonnull interruptingElement) {

    if ([interruptingElement.buttons[@"OK"] exists])
    {
        [interruptingElement.buttons[@"OK"] tap];
        [app tap];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}];
```

I tried implementing this in my setUp and testExample functions, and again it runs fine on simulator and physical devices, however fails on a bot with the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that a system alert WAS what was causing the problem -- for whatever reason, my UIInterruptionMoniter wasn't running properly on the bot. Disabling the notification permission alert during testing fixed my problem.